# An other presentation for the posts?

Tags: feature-request

I'm wondering if this post is well published here. Well, it's a feedback after all.

I'm killing my eyes reading the questions and answers on this website. I'm not sure, maybe I'm the only one to ask for this, but could be really fine if the presentation change to a fluid one instead of a static layout, such that I can make shorter lines with bigger letters, as on Wikipedia.

In short, I want to be able to reflow the text of this site.

How can I do that ?

**EDIT:** Apparently, the mobile version of StackExchange allows to read more easily. So far, I've been unable to notice the difference in the address (like the *m* in front of the usual Wikipedia page for the mobile version for instance). So two other question:

- Does the mobile version really allow to reflow the text ?
- Is there a way to force the mobile version of SE on a computer   ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You browser should let you increase the font size (command-+ on a mac. I suspect ctrl-+ on windows, but don't know for sure). I've got rather a small screen but I can still increase by two steps with getting horizontal scroll bars.

Comment: Yep, and also most (all?) of the major browsers will let you scale up the default font size in the browser settings. So I don't think this is something that Stack Exchange will implement as a feature of the website.

Comment: Yes, I know this. The point is that it is well known that to read efficiently the number of words per line should not be too large. That's why newspapers are written in columns. That's what I would like to do, I would like to reflow the text. Zooming up, or rescaling the text size just increase the text size, it does not reflow it.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own user stylesheet (using Stylish or another such browser plugin). While such a feature may be useful to some, I don't see a pressing need for this.

Here's a suggestion: Use [this script of mine](https://stackapps.com/q/3307/10098) (which takes a post and trips out everything surrounding it so that it can be printed). Then, use Ctrl-+ or Ctrl-Scroll to zoom in.

Comment: Sounds good for me, except that the link you gave is about "Punching a user button"... Is it really a solution to my problem ? :-)

Comment: @Oaoa: Oops; wrong script. Updated. :)

Comment: Ok, it's well done script. Thanks for it. Nevertheless, it still didn't allow to reflow the text, and I need to "print" every post. A script for printing the full page (question + answers) would be better, but still the problem to be abble to reflow remains. Thanks anyways :-)

Comment: @Oaoa: For printing the Q+As there already is [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/)

Comment: But that's exactly what could fit well my request for the moment ! Thanks a lot Manishearth :-)